# Partially forgotten encryption password for Windows users

Tags: encryption, brute-force, passphrase, veracrypt

I encrypted important files with Veracrypt and I remember most of the password but some parts are forgotten. I need some advice as to what would be the most efficient way of getting the encryption password.

My operating system is Windows, I tried BASH solutions but I opened the Veracrypt volume via use of a hex editor and there was some data but I wasn't sure if it was the header key or what to do with it. When I tried using vUte with bash.exe binary for Windows it didn't work well and crushed. Is there an easier way to do this, especially for Windows users?

I've been trying to get the password for months now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse that answer only links to extraction of a TrueCrypt key. The asker posted a follow-up question there two days ago, so I don't see this as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

The reason no one has been answering your current question and the follow up question is that there is no existing Windows brute forcing software for the Veracrypt header. Your best bet would be to find a way to brute force the Veracrypt header with THC Hydra/Cygwin.